# No se inserta ruta de imagen PHP y MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, php7

Tengo un listado de registros a los cuales les quiero insertar imágenes usando `id_persona` como llave de enlace a la tabla imágenes. Esta tabla de imágenes sólo tiene 3 campos id_imagen, id_persona(foráneo) y ruta...

El problema es que solo estoy recibiendo las imágenes en la carpeta del servidor, pero la ruta no se inserta...

```
 <?php

 include("conexion.php");
 $id_persona = $_POST['id_persona'];


 //Como el elemento es un arreglos utilizamos foreach para extraer todos los 
 valores
 foreach($_FILES["file"]['tmp_name'] as $key => $tmp_name)
 {
 //Validamos que el archivo exista
 if($_FILES["file"]["name"][$key]) {
    $filename = $_FILES["file"]["name"][$key]; //Obtenemos el nombre 
  original del archivo
    $source = $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"][$key]; //Obtenemos un nombre 
  temporal del archivo

    $directorio = 'imagenes/'; //Declaramos un  variable con la ruta donde 
  guardaremos los archivos

    //Validamos si la ruta de destino existe, en caso de no existir la 
  creamos
    if(!file_exists($directorio)){
        mkdir($directorio, 0777) or die("No se puede crear el directorio de 
  extracci&oacute;n");  
    }

    $dir=opendir($directorio); //Abrimos el directorio de destino
    $target_path = $directorio.'/'.$filename; //Indicamos la ruta de 
  destino, así como el nombre del archivo

    //Creamos consulta
    $query = "INSERT INTO imagenes (id_persona, ruta) values 
   ('$id_persona','$target_path')";
        //Movemos y validamos que el archivo se haya cargado correctamente
    //El primer campo es el origen y el segundo el destino
    if(move_uploaded_file($source, $target_path)) { 
        echo "El archivo $filename se ha almacenado en forma exitosa.<br>";
        } else {    
        echo "Ha ocurrido un error, por favor inténtelo de nuevo.<br>";
    }
    closedir($dir); //Cerramos el directorio de destino
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Ni una ni otra, la solución fue simple y es que mi error era que sólo estaba creando la consulta pero no le estaba dando uso:

```
  <?
  $query = "INSERT INTO imagenes (id_persona, ruta) values 
  (".$id_persona.",'".$target_path."')";
  if(mysqli_query($conn,$query)) {
  echo "Registro guardado correctamente!";
  } else {
  echo "Error: " . mysqli_error($conn);
  }
  ?>
```

Answer (score -1):

En primer lugar verifica que siempre exista un registro de Imagen, eso puede estar fallando, yo ocupo esta forma, tambien esta la parte de que si hay otras imágenes que tengan el mismo nombre por eso yo lo trabajo en esta forma

```
$destino = '../images/galeria_imagen/';

if (is_uploaded_file($_FILES['imagen']['tmp_name'])) {

   $tmp_name = $_FILES['imagen']['tmp_name'];
   $name = $_FILES['imagen']['name'];
   $nombre_nuevo_al_producto = 'nombre_imagen';
   $nombre_tipo_nuevo_al_producto = 'jpg';
   $variable_ingreso = "";
   $data = true;
   do{
        $data = false;
        $directorio = opendir($destino);

        if($contador_lista_archivo_producto>0){
            $variable_ingreso = $nombre_nuevo_al_producto.$contador_lista_archivo_producto.'.'.$nombre_tipo_nuevo_al_producto;
        }else{
            $variable_ingreso = $nombre_nuevo_al_producto.'.'.$nombre_tipo_nuevo_al_producto;
        }

        while ($archivo = readdir($directorio)) //obtenemos un archivo y luego otro sucesivamente
        {
            if($variable_ingreso == $archivo){
                $contador_lista_archivo_producto = $contador_lista_archivo_producto+1;
                $data = true;
            }
        }
    }while($data);

    if(rename($tmp_name, $destino.$variable_ingreso)){                  
        $_GRABAR_SQL2 = "insert into image(nombre, direccion, tipo) values ('".$variable_ingreso."','images/galeria_imagen/".$variable_ingreso."','".$tipo_ingresa_data."'); ";

        $count = $conexion->exec($_GRABAR_SQL2);
    }

}
```

Adactala a tu gusto y verifica.

Comment: La validación no me ha servido como lo tienes, debido a que la ruta con el nombre de la imagen yo lo guardo en una sola variable....

Answer (score -3):

Ya es posible que exista una id_persona registrada con ese valor? Debes asegurarte de ello antes de usar INSERT . En ese caso la consulta debe cambiar a la forma:

```
UPDATE ... ....  WHERE 'id_persona' = $id_persona
```

No específicas en tu problema si al menos el campo id_persona se inserta correctamente. Hace tiempo no uso PHP con MySQL pero debes chequear el modo de crear el query porque muchas veces hay errores en símbolos como paréntesis y comillas.

Lo más importante, has creado una cadena que es el texto del query pero no lo ejecutas, debes agregar mysql_query($query) o algo muy similar  para ejecutarlo.

Comment: @ Greydel Perez Ferrer Me devuelve error:                                    ``$act = "INSERT INTO imagenes (id_persona, ruta) values ('$id_persona','$target_path') WHERE id_persona = '$id_persona'";``

Comment: `INSERT` no soporta la claúsula  `WHERE`. en todo caso habría que usar `UPDATE`

Comment: @Javi Ps , pero lo que necesito es insertar

Comment: Lo que dije al final de mi respuesta